# Loki: Canon Pixma MG 5250 Scanner not working/detected

Tags: release-loki, printer

I am using a Canon MG 5250 wireless all-in-one printer/scanner. While the printer is detected without any problem and all printing functions work out of the box, the scanner is not working at all.

I tried using simple scan, which results in an error stating that no scanner is connected.

Do I have to install any additional drivers or something? Before upgrading to Loki the scanner/printer functions worked both out of the box in Freya...

Looking forward to your answers... Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the scanner to work you have to download and install the [drivers from canon](http://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg5250.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Linux%20(64-bit)). This also supplies a scanner program that should work with your scanner.

The installation is done by untarring the downloaded file by right clicking on it and selecting expand here (could be slightly different as i am translating from a dutch system). This will create a new folder in the same folder as the downloaded file with the same name as the filename of the download.

This folder contains a couple of files. select the one ending with -deb.tar.gz. Right click on it and select expand here. This will create a new folder in the same folder you are working in. Right click this folder and select open in terminal

This will again create a new folder in the folder you are working in. Right click this folder and select open in, and terminal in the menu that appears.

Type

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

in the terminal and press enter. Enter your password when prompted.

Now you can scan using the program canon provided, unfortunately the build in scanner program won't work, and the canon program won't appear in the applications menu. To start the canon program open the terminal from the menu. In the terminal type

```
scangearmp
```

and press enter. The canon program will open and should find your scanner.

Comment: thank you, very useful - just helped my neighbour with his Canon printer

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much! The Canon Tool is pretty good, totally usable instead of simple scan... On more hint for you and whom it may concern. You can easily create a starter for the Canon application in a few steps:

1. Open Scratch
2. Type or copy paste the following:

[Desktop Entry]

Type=Application

Name=ScanGear

GenericName=Canon ScanGear MP

GenericName[de]=Canon ScanGear MP

Comment[de]=Canon Scanner Tool

Exec=scangearmp

Icon=*Path to image file* (Download one u like for that app)

Categories=Office

3. Save file as ScanGear.desktop or any other name u prefer.
4. Copy or move file to: /usr/share/applications/

Thank you and have fun!